# How to get List Items from sharepoint using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I want to get a collection of `ListItem` from a Sharepoint List (O365) using Microsoft Graph. I have used the following URI but it is returninga "Bad Request" error.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}?expand=fields(select=Title,Product)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you *really* shouldn't use the `/beta` Graph in production code. It is not stable and breaking changes can (and do) happen without warning. Unless you have a very specific need, always use `/v1.0`.

I believe your problem here is that you're attempting to select `Title` from the `Fields` collection. This property isn't actually a member of `Fields`, it is part of the `ListItem` itself. Try this instead:

```
?$select=title,fields&$expand=$fields($select=product)
```